# OpenCV Hough Detection finding inner circle

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to use Hough circle detection method to find all the circle as shown in the image(shown in image 1 and 2). Initially, I used canny and findContour method (shown in image 3). I'm still unsure which method will be more suitable.The problem with the canny and findContour method was that it didn't find all the circles as well as getting lot of noise. But when using the Hough circle detection, the circle is sometimes catching the outer perimeter instead of the inner as shown in image 2.

The canny+findcontour methods finds the circle contour well but has a lot of noise whereas Hough circle works well but the circles sometimes blends with the outer circle.

[Hough circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYHt8.png)

[Hough circle-zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT2jo.png)

[canny + findcontour method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/920EW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get better results if you pre-process the image. First apply Otsu thresholding, if that doesn't work well use a manual value for threshold. After that use the cv.erode() function to get a crisp boundary. Then try to apply the Hough circle transform.
If performance is not an issue, another interesting thing would be to to look at Holistically Nested Edge Detection and then apply Hough circle transform.

Also have a look at the following:

https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html